How to update values of duplicate records to new sequential values
I am trying to write a SQL query that will find rows that have duplicate values in 2 specific columns and will then update the values of the duplicates to new sequential values.
For Example if a given table has the following results beforehand:



id
sequence
data1
data2




1
1
...



1
1




2
1




2
2




3
1




3
1




3
1





Should update to:



id
sequence
data1
data2




1
1
...



1
2




2
1




2
2




3
1




3
2




3
3





This is the script I wrote to try and accomplish this, but it seems to just change the sequence value to 1 for all the id rows that have duplicates.
WITH DuplicateRecords AS (
   SELECT id, 
          sequence,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, sequence ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum
   FROM table1
   WHERE Id IN (
      SELECT id
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY id, sequence
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
   )
),
UPDATE table1
SET sequence = DR.RowNum
FROM table1
JOIN DuplicateRecords DR ON table1.id = DR.id
WHERE table1.id IN (
   SELECT id
   FROM table1
   GROUP BY id, sequence
   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)


please try to remove sequence from ROW_NUMBER()

You forgot to fill the expected and actual values

How do you know which row gets which sequence? Is there a timestamp column or something else that can indicate the natural order?

Just update the CTE...
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT,
    sequence INT,
    data1 VARCHAR(100), 
    data2 VARCHAR(100)  
);


INSERT INTO table1 (id, sequence, data1, data2)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'data1_value1', 'data2_value1'),
(1, 1, 'data1_value2', 'data2_value2'),
(2, 1, 'data1_value3', 'data2_value3'),
(2, 2, 'data1_value4', 'data2_value4'),
(3, 1, 'data1_value5', 'data2_value5'),
(3, 1, 'data1_value6', 'data2_value6'),
(3, 1, 'data1_value7', 'data2_value7');


7 rows affected

WITH DuplicateRecords AS (
    SELECT id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, sequence, data1, data2) AS NewSequence, 
           sequence, 
           data1, 
           data2
    FROM table1
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING MIN(sequence) <> 1
            OR COUNT(DISTINCT sequence) <> COUNT(*)
            OR MAX(sequence) <> COUNT(*)
    )
)
UPDATE DuplicateRecords 
SET sequence = NewSequence

5 rows affected

SELECT * FROM table1; 




id
sequence
data1
data2




1
1
data1_value1
data2_value1


1
2
data1_value2
data2_value2


2
1
data1_value3
data2_value3


2
2
data1_value4
data2_value4


3
1
data1_value5
data2_value5


3
2
data1_value6
data2_value6


3
3
data1_value7
data2_value7



fiddle
Edit : I tried to down vote my answer, but I'm not allowed. Will delete if @MartinSmith adds the following as an answer...
WITH DuplicateRecords AS (
    SELECT id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, sequence, data1, data2) AS NewSequence, 
           sequence, 
           data1, 
           data2
    FROM table1
)
UPDATE DuplicateRecords 
SET sequence = NewSequence
WHERE sequence <> NewSequence


@MartinSmith Because I was too fixated on fixing the mistakes in the Op's CTE and couldn't see the wood for the trees...

You need to match not just on id and sequence, but also on data1 and data2 to make that the correct duplicate rows are updated and this way you prevent multiple updates to the same rows.
The sequence will need to be updated with a sequential number for each duplicate set within the same id.
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    id INT,
    sequence INT,
    data1 VARCHAR(100), 
    data2 VARCHAR(100)  
);


INSERT INTO table1 (id, sequence, data1, data2)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'data1_value1', 'data2_value1'),
(1, 1, 'data1_value2', 'data2_value2'),
(2, 1, 'data1_value3', 'data2_value3'),
(2, 2, 'data1_value4', 'data2_value4'),
(3, 1, 'data1_value5', 'data2_value5'),
(3, 1, 'data1_value6', 'data2_value6'),
(3, 1, 'data1_value7', 'data2_value7');


WITH DuplicateRecords AS (
    SELECT id, 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS NewSequence, 
           sequence, 
           data1, 
           data2
    FROM table1
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY id, sequence
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    )
)
UPDATE t
SET t.sequence = DR.NewSequence
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN DuplicateRecords DR
    ON t.id = DR.id 
    AND t.sequence = DR.sequence
    AND t.data1 = DR.data1
    AND t.data2 = DR.data2;


SELECT * FROM table1;




id
sequence
data1
data2




1
1
data1_value1
data2_value1


1
2
data1_value2
data2_value2


2
1
data1_value3
data2_value3


2
2
data1_value4
data2_value4


3
1
data1_value5
data2_value5


3
2
data1_value6
data2_value6


3
3
data1_value7
data2_value7



fiddle

Assumes that (id, sequence, data1, data2) is unique.

Instead, just use an updatable CTE ; https://dbfiddle.uk/vtW_WIJg

You should post that as an answer, @MatBailie .
